# Release CGDataProviderWithCopyOfData when applying filter

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios7.1

I have a method that applies a tint effect filter and creates a CGBitmapContext. Every time when a user taps the filter's button, it increases the memory and the memory is not freed by ARC. It adds 600KB every time. I've done some research and found on **Instruments Allocations** that Core Graphics adds 600KB on **CGDataProviderWithCopyOfData**. How can i release this **CGRaster data**?

Here is the method:

```
-(UIImage *)modifyImageTintColor:(UIImage *)source imageRawData:(Byte *)rawData degree:(int)degree{

double PI = 3.14159;
double HALF_CIRCLE_DEGREE = 180;
double RANGE = 256;

int RY, GY, BY, RYY, GYY, BYY, R, G, B, Y;
double angle = (PI * (double)degree) / HALF_CIRCLE_DEGREE;

int S = (int)(RANGE * sin(angle));
int C = (int)(RANGE * cos(angle));

CGFloat r, g, b;
//apply sepia effect

int byteIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < _imageWidth * _imageHeight; ++i){

    r = rawData[byteIndex];
    g = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
    b = rawData[byteIndex + 2];

    RY = ( 70 * r - 59 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
    GY = (-30 * r + 41 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
    BY = (-30 * r - 59 * g + 89 * b ) / 100;
    Y  = ( 30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b ) / 100;
    RYY = ( S * BY + C * RY ) / 256;
    BYY = ( C * BY - S * RY ) / 256;
    GYY = (-51 * RYY - 19 * BYY ) / 100;
    R = Y + RYY;
    R = ( R < 0 ) ? 0 : (( R > 255 ) ? 255 : R );
    G = Y + GYY;
    G = ( G < 0 ) ? 0 : (( G > 255 ) ? 255 : G );
    B = Y + BYY;
    B = ( B < 0 ) ? 0 : (( B > 255 ) ? 255 : B );

    rawData[byteIndex] = R;
    rawData[byteIndex + 1] = G;
    rawData[byteIndex + 2] = B;

    byteIndex += 4;


}

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * _imageWidth;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef imageRef;

CGContextRef ctx;
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            _imageWidth,
                            _imageHeight,
                            bitsPerComponent,
                            bytesPerRow,
                            colorSpace,
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CFRelease(ctx);

return result;
```

}

Comment: Is there someone that has an answer???

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `CFRelease` on `imageRef` like this:

```
imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CFRelease (imageRef);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CFRelease(ctx);
```

Also it can look neater (and be more readable) to always use CFRelease instead of the custom releasers like this:

```
imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CFRelease (imageRef);
CGRelease(ctx);
CGRelease(colorSpace);
CFRelease(ctx);
```

Comment: U cannot call CFRelease on CGImageRef

Comment: You can call CFRelease on `imageRef`. Here is the Apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageRelease) for `CGImageRelesae` on CGImageRef, take a look at the discussion section.